# How to debug Nodejs/Expressjs(MEAN stack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I started working on MEAN stack recently and being a fan of javascript I am enjoying learning it. I sometimes extremely hard to debug the code and end up doing a lot of greps, console.logs . Is there is better way to debug, preferably stepin, step out way of debugging.

I started with the boiler plate code of MEAN.io .

Comment: is this http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html what you are looking for?

Comment: I would prefer IDE based debugger having come from eclipse+java world but even that would be something I will start using.

Comment: Well it is not that much different than what eclipse would offer in a Java environment. The only difference is, you would use the console (within your IDE) to debug, step in, over, inspect etc.

Comment: Take a look at node-inspector https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: web-storm has some really nice node-debugger built-in.